# What is output of following code?

Tags: c++

What will be the output of code

> `int a=3,b=4;`
>   `++a*=++b;`
>   `cout<<a<<endl;`

compiler shows `a=20` output.How `precedence` and `operator  associativity`  is being used here?

## What I understand is:

first `b` on the left of `++a*=++b;` is incremented us its `unary` operator then comes the 
turn of `*=` so
expression becomes `++a = a * ++b;` as `a=3` and `b=5` now so it becomes `15` then `15` is assigned to `a` and incremented.Finally getting `16` but compiler gives `20`

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Your code modifies `a` *twice* without an intervening *sequence point*. Therefore your code has *undefined behaviour*. See cHao's link for a detailed explanation.

Comment: It's undefined behavior due to lack of sequence points. It's plausible that 4*5 = 20; however, you don't know what the result of the ++a will be so it's undefined.

Comment: @Infinity - Please check out the Beginners section of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You *definitely* need a good book to read.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case on your particular compiler, it seems that first a is incremented to 4 and b is incremented to 5, then a *= b executes and a becomes 20 (4*5). However other compiler could give different result because it is not a defined behaviour as people mentioned in comments

Comment: That's a plausible explanation of the observed behavior. In general, though, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the standards for both C and C++ that the behavior is undefined when you modify the same object twice without a sequence point in between.  That the math happens to work out means nothing; it could operate totally different with another compiler, or between runs of the same program...or, technically, set your computer on fire.

Comment: I thought that ++a and ++b will always happen before multiplication, is that wrong?

Comment: @Martinsos When you have undefined behaviour there is nothing that 'always happens'. The code is not valid C++, there no expected behaviour from this code. `c = ++a * ++b` would work as you say, but the code above is not like that because a is modified twice. That's the problem.

Comment: I think you are right as associativity of `*=` is lesser than ++a so `++a` will be solved earlier.

Comment: @InfinitySignal It's undefined behaviour, your understanding is incomplete. Associativity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Should I delete my answer hm? I like your comments so I don't like idea of deleting it

Comment: @Martinsos Your answer looks fine to me now, I removed my down vote.

Comment: I added a bit to the wording; wanted to stress up front that the results the OP mentions are specific to the OP.